# Mongodb: kern.sched unavailable

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I am quite new to mongodb. After install it via: `brew intall mongodb` then type `mongod` in the terminal, error throws out: `kern.sched unavailable`.

I am using mac os verion 10.6.8.

The log:

```
Sat Apr 13 16:40:56.374 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6387 port=27017 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=fatbizkit
Sat Apr 13 16:40:56.374 [initandlisten]
Sat Apr 13 16:40:56.374 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Sat Apr 13 16:40:56.374 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.1
Sat Apr 13 16:40:56.374 [initandlisten] git version: 1560959e9ce11a693be8b4d0d160d633eee75110
Sat Apr 13 16:40:56.374 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-1.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:$
Sat Apr 13 16:40:56.374 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Sat Apr 13 16:40:56.374 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/usr/local/var/mong$
Sat Apr 13 16:40:56.375 [initandlisten] journal dir=/usr/local/var/mongodb/journal
Sat Apr 13 16:40:56.375 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Sat Apr 13 16:40:56.441 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Sat Apr 13 16:40:56.442 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017  
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.416 got signal 2 (Interrupt), will terminate after current cmd ends
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.416 [interruptThread] now exiting
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.416 dbexit:
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.416 [interruptThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.416 [interruptThread] closing listening socket: 9  
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.416 [interruptThread] closing listening socket: 10
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.416 [interruptThread] closing listening socket: 11
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.416 [interruptThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.417 [interruptThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.417 [interruptThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.417 [interruptThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.417 [interruptThread] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.417 [interruptThread] shutdown: final commit...
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.432 [interruptThread] shutdown: closing all files...
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.442 [interruptThread] closeAllFiles() finished
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.442 [interruptThread] journalCleanup...
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.442 [interruptThread] removeJournalFiles
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.442 [interruptThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sat Apr 13 16:41:29.442 dbexit: really exiting now
```

I tried google, but no luck. Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

After installing mongodb with brew and typing the command mongod I had the same error, and the same logs. I left the terminal opened.
I opened another terminal window, and typed the command mongo and i am now on mongodb command line.
I could also see that mongodb was running in a browser on the following url : `http://localhost:28017/` 
As it work i left the error for now, I'll try to find an answer later.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yep, actually after posted, it worked, but same errors still shows. Perhaps this is a warning instead of an error?

Comment: Yes that's what I also thought, but at least you're not blocked anymore.

Answer (score 0):

what mongodb version are you using?

log statements you post did not show any info about the error, can you try to reproduce again and send detailed logs?

Did you try to re-install or install from other source?

Regards,
Moacy

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after using a startup file from http://hunterford.me/mongodb-startup-item/ . I do not know if this is the only possible cause of the error you describe, but it was in my case.

The cause of the error seemed to be that in the startup file there was the segment:

```
<string>/usr/local/bin/mongod</string>
```

Which may or may not be where mongod is actually installed. I installed mongo using macports, so I found mongod to be in opt/local/bin - [YMMV](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary)

Once I had changed the directory value in the startup item to the correct one, I no longer had this problem, though I have had further problems with my "soft rlimits being too low", [Solutions to this exist](https://superuser.com/questions/261023/how-to-change-default-ulimit-values-in-mac-os-x-10-6) but since you are using mac os x for mongo, I suspect you're developing/demonstrating and so this *probably* won't be a problem.

I hope this helps.